# Sending MongoDB results with Node

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

I use the following very basic script create a server:

```
var http = require('http');
var queryResult = '';  
const PORT=8080; 
function handleRequest(request, response){
    fetchResult("user1");  //string is a placeholder, but works for now
    setTimeout(function() {
        // **POSSIBLE SOLUTION SPOT A**
        response.end("some text");
    }, 1000);
}
var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);
server.listen(PORT, function(){});
```

I've broken this up just because I think its easier to read.  But on the same page I also the following:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/my_database_name';

function fetchResult(query){
    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
      if (!err) {
        var collection = db.collection('users');
        collection.find({name: query}).toArray(function (err, result) {
          if (result.length)
             queryResult = result;
             // **POSSIBLE SOLUTION SPOT B**
          db.close();
        });
      }
    });
}
```

This works.  It result is an object that has values from my database.  And the server is able to write "some text" when someone makes a request.  However, I can't get it so that the object is written onto the page or otherwise transferred when the user makes the request.  What is the best way to do this?

Notes:
1) I know that using the timeout here is INSANELY bad.  I couldn't figure out how to make the callback work properly and it works well enough for this example.  I'll play through that myself issue once I solve the issue I've described above.

2) I think that JSON.stringify() may play a role in this, but I cant figure out what to do with it.

3) I don't want to use any other module (like express) just yet.  I'm trying to understand how I would achieve the desired result with just the http module.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the Frankenstein code you're trying to write:

```
var http = require('http');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
const PORT=8080;

var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/my_database_name';

function handleRequest(request, response){
  fetchResult("user1");
  MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (!err) {
      var collection = db.collection('users');
      collection.find({name: query}).toArray(function (err, result) {
        if (result.length)
           response.end(JSON.stringify(result));
        db.close();
      });
    }
  });
}
var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);
server.listen(PORT, function(){});
```

As you said yourself, don't use this in production - it's a messy, unreadable blob. `setTimeout` has been removed because I'm not sure what you were trying to accomplish with it.